# Convert t-test summary to a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, attributeerror, t-test, scipy.stats

I performed a t-test on my dataframe and want to access the p-values from the t-test results. Some have suggested to use .summary of the t-test results shown below:

```
cat1 = df[df['Drug']=='Drug A']
cat2 = df[df['Drug']=='Drug B']
results = ttest_ind(cat1['intake'], cat2['intake'])
pvals = results.summary()
```

But i get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Ttest_indResult' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: ```results``` can be accessed like a tuple. ```results[0]``` is what you want. See the return type from documentation. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html

Comment: Thank you! I can access the output now. Not sure how I can set your comment as the answer to this question